# Timeout for redisGetReply

Tags: redis, hiredis

Can I have timeout for redisGetReply?
My current code is

```
 while(redisGetReply(context,&reply) == REDIS_OK) {
        //Check for isstopped 
         if yes return    
        // consume message
        freeReplyObject(reply);
    }
```

Currently if I signal SIGINT to the program. Currently if I signal for SIGINT and this thread in redisGetReply. It will wait till there is any message from server.

How to make redisGetReply stop on some siganl or have a timeout for readreply ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see  in this link

[Testing hiredis example](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/deps/hiredis/test.c)

You can set the timeout just before calling redisGetReply

```
struct timeval tv = { 0, 1000 };
assert(redisSetTimeout(c,tv) == REDIS_OK);
test_cond(redisGetReply(c,&_reply) == REDIS_ERR &&
        c->err == REDIS_ERR_IO && errno == EAGAIN);
redisFree(c);
```